# Loops for calculating vegetation indices for multiple images and each image have multiple bands

Tags: r, loops, stack, calculator, raster

I am a beginner in programmation

I have a raster stack of 40 elements

The stack 'images' is created using 3 bands (RGB) of drone. So each image have multiple bands. The sequence of the rasters in the stack is:

```
Position [[1]]: red band image 1
Position [[2]]: green band image 1
Position [[3]]: blue band image 1
Position [[4]]: red band image 2
Position [[5]]: green band image 2 
Position [[6]]: blue band image 2 
Position [[7]]: red band image 3 
...
```

I want to derive  vegetation index for each image: `(40 EXG = excess green) : EXG = (2* green band - red band - blue band) /255`. I divided by 255 to normalized the index.

So far I have doing it manually. For example:

```
EXG1-> (2*images[[2]] - images[[1]]) - images[[3]])/255
EXG2-> (2*images[[5]] - images[[4]]) - images[[6]])/255
etc.
```

Since my raster stack as a pattern, I am looking for an automatic way to derive the indices. Something like a loop that calculates the index, save it with the appropriate name and then moves to the next 'position' to repeat the process.

Any help on that please?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is 40 images in stack, each with 3 bands something like:

```r
indices <- data.frame(image_nr = integer(), index = double())
for (i in 1:40) {
  EXG -> (2*images[[i*3-1]] - images[[i*3-2]] - images[[i*3]]) /255
  newrow <- data.frame(image_nr = i, index = EXG)
  indices <- rbind(indices, newrow)
}
```